# When a vector space will be a complete lattice?

Tags: vector-spaces, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $E$ a vector space, and let $P$ a strict cone in $E$ (i.e) $P\subset E$ verify: 
$$
\mathbb{R}^+ P\subset P \\
P+P\subset P\\
P\cap (-P)=\{0\}
$$
So we can easily construct a partial order on $E$ which is :
$$
x,y\in E \qquad x\leq_{P}y \iff y-x\in P
$$
My question is for which condition on $P$, $E$ will be a complete lattice ?

Comment: Nice question! $\;\!$

Comment: What are $\mathbb{R}^+ P$, $P+P$ and $-P$?

Comment: that mean :
1) $\mathbb{R}^+ P=\{tx/  t\geq 0 \; x\in P\}$
2) $P+P=\{x+y / x,y\in P\}$
3) $-P=\{-x / x\in P\}$

Comment: are the finite dimensional cone-induced lattices all isomorphic to $P = \Bbb R^{+n} \subset E = \Bbb R^n$ ?

Comment: this is a good question that i don't have an answer @mercio

Comment: I do not understand; from googling definitions, a complete lattice must be a bounded lattice.  How can a positive ray in $P$ for instance have an upper bound in $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if and only if $E=P=0$. If $x$ is the top element in $E$, then $x \geq 0$. This means that by definition $x = x-0 \in P$. Since $x$ is the top element $x \geq 2x$ meaning that $-x = x-2x \in P$ or equivalently $x \in -P$. It follows that $x=0$ since $P \cap -P = \{0\}$. For each $y$ in $E$ since $x$ is the top element $x\geq -y$ meaning that $y=x-(-y)$ is in $P$. It follows that $P=E$ and therefore that $E = E \cap -E = P \cap -P = \{0\}$. Trivially if $E=P=0$ then $E$ is a complete lattice.